# Significance of SSRS roles? Reports depending on permission of Stored procs

Tags: security, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a set of SSRS reports using stored procedures and I want to give view-only access of reports to someone. I believed this could be done by assigning the users/groups "Browser" SSRS role. But its not working.

The grant/deny of reports access could only be done by grant/deny of EXECUTE permission on the underlying stored procs.

Am I missing something here? If the above is true, What is the significance of SSRS roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Source permissions are different from Report access permissions.

SSRS roles do control whether a user can access the report. The report Data Source is most likely set up to pass user credentials to the database and hence the stored procedures; this is why you're needing to set the permissions at that level, too.

If the user had no access to the reports they would not be able to run them and no database access would even occur.

To look at it a different way, consider a report where the credentials are stored at the Data Source and not just passed through using Windows authentication. This means that any user running the report will connect to the database with those stored credentials, not as themselves. You would only need to worry about database permissions for the Data Source credentials. You still need to able to grant/deny access to the report, and this is where Report access permissions will make a difference.

**Edit after comment:**

You've mentioned two scenarios, one where the Data Source is set up to store the database user credentials, and the other where the Data Source database access is set up to use the credentials of whomever is running the report.

In both scenarios you control access to the report itself at the Report Server level.

So, if you grant **Domain\User1** the *Browser* role directly at the report level or higher, they can access the report. With no access set up, **Domain\User2** cannot run the report.

Now that the report permission is set up you need to consider how the Data Source is set up.

When credentials are stored at the Data Source, you only need to consider the database permissions for this user. Say you have set up the Data Source to connect to the database as **Domain\ReportUser** - only this user will need access to the underlying stored procedures. **Domain\User1** does not access the database so does not need `EXECUTE` on these objects; only **Domain\ReportUser** does.

When credentials are not stored, the Data Source database access will be performed by the user running the report, so in this case when **Domain\User1** runs the report, they will also be running the underlying stored procedures so will need the `EXECUTE` privilege on the objects.

In both Data Source scenarios, **Domain\User2** cannot access the report because of the report permissions so the database permissions don't matter.

Comment: Thx for reply Ian. You are right. I just checked my SSRS security settings for Reports Datasource, its passing credentials to the data source and "Use as windows credentials when connecting to the data source" is checked. I am wondering what is means..Can throw some light ? I guess in my situation I should not be passing stored credentials to Reports datasource but rather should use "Windows integrated security"

Comment: I am still confused.. I unchecked "Credentials stored in this report server" and used "windows integrated security". Now I add domain\User1 to Browser role, tried to open reports from windows machine logged in as domain\User1, I still cannot see the reports. Do I have to give any specific database permission to domain\user1... Can you tell me steps to make domain\user1 see the reports but domain\user2 cannot.

Comment: @Subhasis, I've added a bit more detail. Short answer is that report permissions will control access, but depending on how the Data Source is set up, you may need to consider database permissions for individual users, too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and I appreciate your patience. I completely got your point. Lets focus on the case in which Reports datasource is setup to store the credentials of **Domain\ReportUser**. **Domain\User1** is no where in the picture, does not have "Content" role, no rights in database whatsoever, still he is able to view the reports. I dont have explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it must be something else in your environment setup. All I can think of is that the permissions are set a higher level, e.g. the `Home` folder, and these are being propagated down to the actual report. If you don't get anywhere with this, you could try a new install of SSRS, redeploy the reports and see how that goes, but obviously that might not be possible in a production environment. Sorry it didn't help you out.